# Execution failed for task app:generateDebugRFile Error: ':' is not a valid resource name character

Tags: android, xml, build

I just updated to Android Studio 3.3
Now the build failes with

> org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures.
>
> Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task :app:generateDebugRFile'
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: ':' is not a valid resource name character

I searched all xml files with grep for ":", but I didn't find anything.
How can I determine which xml file is affected?

I was able to work around the problem by switching back to the old Android plugin version 3.2.1 (instead of 3.3.0)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'm also receiving same error after updating to 3.3

Comment: no, I will wait for next Android plugIn version

Comment: I found the answer

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in one of my older project when I ported it to Android Studio 3.3

Select Analyze > Code Inspect. It will find all your problematic xml files. In my case it was giving error in an external library which was using ListView with this attribute `android:id = "@+id/android:list"` so I replaced it with `android:id="@+id/list"` and everything worked like a charm.

Comment: thank you, thats the solution. Don't forget to change from 'ListView listView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);' to 'ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list);'